# Add string of control variables in formula expressions in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
control_set_1 = "education + income + sex + birth + race + trust_daily"
control_set_2 = "sex + birth + race + trust_daily"

fit_controls <- lm(data = data, dv ~ politics*treatment + control_set_1)
fit_controls_2 <- lm(data = data, dv ~ politics*treatment + control_set_2)
```

I have tried wrapping `control_set_1` in `as.formula(control_set_1)`, to no avail.

I get the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'control_set_1')

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `as.formula(paste("dv ~ politics*treatment", control_set_1, sep = "+"))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest workaround might be to avoid strings and just keep everything as a formula. Then you can use `update()` to change the formula as needed

```
control_set_1 = ~. + education + income + sex + birth + race + trust_daily
control_set_2 = ~. + sex + birth + race + trust_daily

fit_controls <- lm(data = data, update(dv ~ politics*treatment, control_set_1))
fit_controls_2 <- lm(data = data, update(dv ~ politics*treatment, control_set_2))
```

The `.` in the `control_set` formulas keep all existing predictors and just adds the new values in.